# Managing spring boot applications from a web dashboard

Tags: linux, spring-boot, devops

We have multiple spring boot (release 1.4.3) applications each deployed on multiple linux redhat servers. The applications are managed using systemctl commands.

We would like to be able to monitor, stop and start the applications from a web dashbord.

Is there an existing tool to do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 2):

You can read more about spring-boot-admin, [the link is here](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin) 
which provides UI for adminstrating Spring Boot applications.  I have an Spring Boot project and i am using it.

It shows health status, some statistics metrics of memory usage, threads usage and so on.

They don't have the feature to stop/start applications. **In my opinion you should rely on your OSs features to start and stop a process. For example as a init.d-service or in cas you are using docker by controlling your container via kubernetes or sth. else.**  quoted from one of the project contributor. More talkings about the stop/start topic is [here](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/99)